# use event.target to get the class value?

Tags: jquery

i have a DOM element with class='tag'.

i want to check if the class value is tag and alert a message if it's true.

i wrote:

```
    $("#thread").each(function(event) {
        if(event.target.class == 'tag') alert('yes');
    });
```

but it didn't work. you can get the id with event.target.id but not the class with this code? what are all the values you can have after event.target?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At first, the `event` argument work only for event handlers, and you are using the `$.each` method.

I don't really think that you want/need to use the `$.each` method, since you are using an `#id` selector, and id's should be unique.

To check if an element contains an specific class you can use the [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method:

```
if ($("#thread").hasClass('tag')) {
  //...
}
```

Also if you have a DOM element, to get it's class attribute, you should access it with `className` instead `class`, that's because `class` is a *future reserved word* in JavaScript, the same thing happens with other attributes like `for`, should be accessed as `htmlFor`...

Comment: where can i find all the attributes to use with event.target?

Comment: it says event.target is undefined?

Comment: I do `$(event.target).attr("class")` to get class of element clicked, in example. If you have numbered classes you won't write a case for each...

Answer (score 25):

```
if( $(event.target).hasClass("tag") )
{
   alert("yes");
}
```

This will work fine.

Comment: The accepted answer answers the specific example, but this answer answers the question

Answer (score 1):

you are using jquery's each method incorrectly.  it takes two arguments, neither one of them is an event (that would respond to the target property).  from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$.each([52, 97], function(index, value) { 
  alert(index + ': ' + value); 
});
```

See CMS's answer for the proper way of checking if elements have a given class name.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
$("div").each(function (index, domEle) {
    if (domEle.hasClass("tag")) {
        console.log('yes');
    } else {
        console.log('no');
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there way way to figure hour if something doesn't have a class?  The opposite of this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use inside the condition:

```
!domEle.hasClass("tag")
```