# Hide input box once click to other element or mouseup but retain once focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to hide input box once mouseup or click to other element and retain once focus? My current code is below, the mouseup is working but the thing is once focus on showed input boxes, they're being hidden immediately. See the demonstration below and click edit button. Input boxes will show, but will disappear once they are focused.

```js
$(".edit").click(function () {

    var $span = $(this);
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.textdisplay').hide();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.editbox').css("display", "inline");

    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    var RemoveIDedit = ID.replace('edit_', '');
    $(this).hide();
    $("#save_" + RemoveIDedit).css("display", "inline");

});

$(".save").click(function () {

    var $span = $(this);
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.textdisplay').css("display", "inline");

    $(this).closest('tr').find('.editbox').hide();

    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    var RemoveIDsave = ID.replace('save_', '');
    $(this).hide()
    $("#edit_" + RemoveIDsave).css("display", "inline");

});

$(document).mouseup(function () {
    $(".editbox").hide();
    $(".textdisplay").show();
    $(".edit").css("display", "inline");
    $(".save").css("display", "none")
});
```

```css
.save {
    display: none;
}
table {
    width: 400px;
}
}
table td {
    border: 1px solid;
}
.trash {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.save, .edit {
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.editbox {
    font-size:14px;
    display: none;
}
.textdisplay {
    font-size: 14px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> <span class="textdisplay"> Data 1A </span>
            <input type="text" class="editbox" value="Data 1A" />
        </td>
        <td> <span class="textdisplay"> Data 1B </span>
            <input type="text" class="editbox" value="Data 1B" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" id="282" class="trash">Delete</a>
            <a href="#" id="edit_282" class="edit">Edit</a> 
            <a href="#" id="save_282" class="save">Save</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="textdisplay"> Data 2A </span>
            <input type="text" class="editbox" value="Data 2A" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="textdisplay"> Data 2B </span>
            <input type="text" class="editbox" value="Data 2b" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" id="283" class="trash">Delete</a>
            <a href="#" id="edit_283" class="edit">Edit</a> 
            <a href="#" id="save_283" class="save">Save</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6v2880z/)

Comment: it is your mouseup function, that hides the boxes again, because if i want to edit i click in textbox and on mouseup they are removed.... comment your mouseup function and it works as expected.... ah no, ok, no i understood your question, need it only on loosing focus... let me think :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes that works but how can I hide input boxes again if I click to other element?

Comment: try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L6v2880z/4/ i just added a check, that the target from mouse up is not an INPUT box

Comment: actually propably even better if you check if target has class "editbox" and only then return false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so just change your mouseup to following code:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('editbox')) return false;
    $(".editbox").hide();
    $(".textdisplay").show();
    $(".edit").css("display","inline");
    $(".save").css("display","none")
});
```

as in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/L6v2880z/7/

EDIT: Sorry $(this) was the wrong context i used before...

Comment: I see what you mean on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128755/use-event-target-to-get-the-class-value

Comment: Thank you so much! I used the below code and it work!       $(document).mouseup(function (event) {
        
        
    if( $(event.target).hasClass("editbox") ) return false;

Comment: no prob. hope you will make a nice project out of it - looks promising ;)